# T-SQL Pivot one column to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I have a one-column table that can vary in size depending on the day. Let's say the table has 6,000 rows. Is there a way you can pivot this table in T-SQL so that is 6,000 columns without having to specify each column name?

Comment: No.  That would exceed the limit on the number of columns in a SQL Server table.

Comment: Why would you even *want* a dataset with 6,000 columns?! This is must certainly an XY Problem.

Comment: The vendor requesting the output needs the data pivoted into a format where its a single row.